# Why can't i scrape data from other pages except the first one?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

These days i have been trying to scrape data from websites and i have i only still have a problem that keeps me from reaching this goal which is that i can only get the data from the first page while the other pages get crawled but no data is scraped so in the end i only have data from the first page. here is my code any ideas about how i can solve this?:

```
import scrapy
import random
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from scrapy.http import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

USER_AGENTS = [
   ...]

class Alibaba3CrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'alibaba3_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['alibaba.com']
    start_urls = ['http://alibaba.com/']
    search_text = "shoes"
    page_num = 1
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 4,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1.0,
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Alibaba3CrawlerSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # Initialize the Selenium WebDriver and store it in a class variable
        driver_path = GeckoDriverManager().install()
        options = FirefoxOptions()
        options.add_argument("-headless")
        driver_service = FirefoxService(executable_path=driver_path)
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=driver_service, options=options)

    def start_requests(self):
        url = f"https://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.0.0.32521541bYkLGt&fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&keywords={self.search_text}&tab=all&&page={self.page_num}"
        headers = {'User-Agent': random.choice(USER_AGENTS)}
        
        # Include your GitHub Personal Access Token here
        github_token = token
        
        # Set up headers with the token
        headers['Authorization'] = f'token {github_token}'

        yield scrapy.Request(
            url, 
            callback=self.parse, 
            headers=headers, 
            meta={"search_text": self.search_text,
                  "page_num": self.page_num, "github_token": github_token}
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        self.browser.get(response.url)
        
        for _ in range(1):
            self.browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(2)
            
        updated_page_source = self.browser.page_source
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(updated_page_source, 'html.parser')
        product_cards = soup.find_all('div', class_='fy23-search-card fy23-list-card m-gallery-product-item-v2 J-search-card-wrapper')
        data = []
        for card in product_cards:
            title_element = card.find('h2', class_='search-card-e-title')
            title = title_element.text if title_element else None
            price_element = card.find('div', class_='search-card-e-price-main')
            price = price_element.text if price_element else None            
            shipping_per_pair_element = card.find('div', class_="search-card-m-sale-features__item")
            shipping_per_pair = shipping_per_pair_element.text if shipping_per_pair_element else None   
            Supplier_details_element = card.find('div', class_='search-card-e-popper__trigger')         
            Supplier_details = Supplier_details_element.text if Supplier_details_element else None
            rating_element = card.find('span', class_='search-card-e-review')
            rating = rating_element.text if rating_element else None
            other_details_element = card.find('div', class_='search-card-m-product-features__sellPoint')
            other_details = other_details_element.text if other_details_element else None

            data.append({
                'Title': title,
                'Price': price,
                'Rating': rating,
                'Shipping_per_pair': shipping_per_pair,
                'Supplier_details': Supplier_details,
                'Other_Details': other_details
            }) 

        if data:
            yield from data

        current_page_num = response.meta["page_num"]
        if current_page_num < self.settings.get('MAX_PAGES', 2):
            next_page_num = current_page_num + 1
            next_url = f"https://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.0.0.32521541bYkLGt&fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&keywords={self.search_text}&tab=all&&page={next_page_num}"
            headers = {'User-Agent': random.choice(USER_AGENTS)}
            
            github_token = response.meta.get("github_token", "")
            headers['Authorization'] = f'token {github_token}'
            
            yield Request(
                next_url,
                callback=self.parse,
                headers=headers,
                meta={"search_text": response.meta["search_text"],
                      "page_num": next_page_num,
                      "github_token": github_token,
                }
            )
    
    def closed(self, reason):
        self.browser.quit()
```